# How do I get my space ship to move?

Tags: java, render

I made these methods:

```
public Player(double x, double y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();
    SpriteSheet ss = new SpriteSheet(loader.loadImage("/Pics/TheSpriteSheet.png"));
    this.image = ss.grabImage(1, 1, 32, 32);
}
public void tick(){
    this.x++;
}
public void render(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(image, (int) x, (int) y, null);
}
```

Then I put it in my tick method in my main class which gets called every nanosecond or so.

```
public void tick(){
    playerClass.tick();
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are already moving it. What's the problem?

Comment: you need to redraw your ship

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are only updating the space ship's x position but you are not redrawing the screen. Therefore, the x position is increased but you won't see it on your screen!

You might use something like `spaceShip.repaint();`